# Azure Graph API - Application permisisons to update global admin user properties

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I have Azure application/secret and want to update user properties, some users are Global admins,

permisisons are as in picture below:

[image]

For users who are global admins Azure application can update Job title but not mobile phone,getting `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation`.For regular users, able to update both, job description and mobile phone.

Anyone knows if some delegated/application permissions are missing ?

getting new token on new login

```
token = String.IsNullOrEmpty(token) ? getToken(l2.UserName, l2.Password, "https://login.microsoft.com/" + l2.Tenant_ID + "/oauth2/token", l2.URL_Graph) : token;]]
```

token is generated by passing azure app ID/secret

Comment: Could you include what flow you are using to generate access token like client credentials or authorization code?

Comment: Are you passing Azure AD user's username and password to acquire token?

Comment: pasisng AppID/secret, not using standard user but azure principal (Azure application registaration)

Comment: In app-only scenarios, the app must be assigned a higher privileged administrator role to perform sensitive actions. In your case, assign either `Privileged Auth Admin` role or `Global Admin` role to the application.

Comment: hmm, cannot find a way to assign admin role to azure principal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255287/discussion-between-sridevi-and-overflowed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I registered one Azure AD application and added same **API permissions** as below:

[image]

Now I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman by passing app ID and app secret like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to update Global Admin's mobile number, I too got **same error** as below:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/11475d17-d370-4ecc-9bec-xxxxxxxxx/
{
    "mobilePhone": "+91 913xxxxxxx04"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that,    `mobilePhone`  is [**sensitive property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-beta#who-can-perform-sensitive-actions) that requires additional permissions or roles to update.
>
> In app-only scenarios, the app must be assigned a **higher privileged**
> administrator role.

In my case, I assigned **Global Administrator** role to the application like this:

[image]

After assigning the role, I ran the same query by generating token again and got **response** as below:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/11475d17-d370-4ecc-9bec-xxxxxxxxx/
{
    "mobilePhone": "+91 9133xxxxxx4"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, mobile number property **updated** successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Update user - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)